# Algorithm to pair 2 objects within an allowed weight range?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, set, bipartite

I am looking to find a way to pair 2 objects that are +- a certain weight with each other, to create the most pairs possible. Example: I have 100 of said objects, all ranging from 1-100 pounds and are allowed to be paired +-5 pounds off their current weight. How could I most efficiently create the most pairs. I have a unique identifier and their weight and I am comparing them all to the same set. I looked into some algorithms (Hungarian) but not sure which I could apply to this issue and how, so any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sort the objects by weight. Repeat until no objects remain: if the lightest two are within five pounds, pair and remove them. Otherwise, remove the lightest.

This greedy algorithm can be proved optimal.